# ElasticSearch query specific fields return arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

I using ElasticSearch 2.4 for storing documents. For query them, I call this command:

```
{
   "query":{
      "query_string":{
         "default_field":"Text",
         "query": "This is my full search query"
      },
   }
}
```

and the results are, for example:

```
{
   "took":2,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":862,
      "max_score":4.1904,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"education",
            "_type":"e353edaa-9b83-419b-952b-888b5db21928",
            "_id":"9b015845-07b1-499d-96fa-c0ede2d60f46",
            "_score":4.1904,
            "_source":{
               "Shared":true,
               "Text":"Hello world hello world hello world",
               "ID":"9b015845-07b1-499d-96fa-c0ede2d60f46",
               "UserId":"e2223edaa-9b83-419b-952b-888b5db21928",
               "PublishDate":"2017-04-13T11:55:25.2394266Z"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now, instead of transferring all the "record" over the network, I want to send the same query, but now, the returned information will include only few fields (`ID` and `PublishedDate`). So I calling this query:

```
{
   "fields" : ["ID", "PublishDate"],
   "query":{

      "query_string":{
         "default_field":"Text",
         "query": "Hello"
      },
   }
}
```

and the results are looking like:

```
{
   "took":43,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":1,
      "max_score":0.09824822,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"education",
            "_type":"410c24b1-78a8-4ee4-984d-9cfa2331120f",
            "_id":"63ea1591-7126-4512-9c8b-2e3fcdcc5081",
            "_score":0.09824822,
            "fields":{
               "PublishDate":[
                  "2018-02-28T23:28:08.8376343Z"
               ],
               "ID":[
                  "63ea1591-7126-4512-9c8b-2e3fcdcc5081"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, the two fields (`PublishedDate` and `ID`) are return as **string array**. I don't understand why?

The first query (mentioned here) just proved that this "record" have only one `ID` ("9b015845-07b1-499d-96fa-c0ede2d60f46") and only one `PublishedDate` ("2017-04-13T11:55:25.2394266Z"). So why it's returned as array when asking for specific fields in the results?

Anyone have explanation?

Comment: it returns an array of fields because you have insert a fields clause in your query. Also this output has only one PublishedDate and one ID

Comment: Correct me if I wrong, but the `fields` clause should just send me specific fields in the response. Not change their values. By returning string array it's changing their type.

Comment: no, the 'fields' field in your output is a string array. You have requested an array with only this two parameters and not querying to return in output the _source metafield, that show you the how the source appears in your docs

Comment: OK. Got you. So I just have to change the clause "fields" to "_source" and it's working. Thanks.